# Can I make this one line of matrix multiplication and addition code more efficient?

Tags: matlab, performance, matrix, matrix-multiplication, processing-efficiency

This one line of code is currently taking ~50% of the processing time. Is there a more efficient way of processing this line?

```
o = o + sum(sum(im.*p))*p/sum(sum(p)));
```

The variables (*im*,*p* & *o*) are all 2D matrices of size 1000x1000 (ish).

- '***im***'   is a fixed matrix that has constant values
- '***p***'    is a sparse matrix that changes on each iteration
- '***o***'    is a matrix that increases on each iteration that is reset after
  1000(ish) iterations of the code block.

Let me know if you need more information, or I need to clarify anything I've said. Thank you for your answers/feedback in advance.

Comment: Try this: `o = o + (im(:).' * p(:))*p/sum(p(:));` (Not sure if that would be helpful.)

Comment: The fact that it's a sparse matrix will give you trouble.  Because you are possibly mixing full and sparse matrices together, the operation on the sparse matrix automatically gets promoted to a full matrix and so this conversion will take up time.  The above comment by Sardar may help, but I highly doubt it will provide any more computational savings beyond that.

Comment: Sardar, your method saved about 20% I think.

Comment: Rayryeng, using sparse matrices vastly increases the speed for other parts of the process